# How to subclass a class defined with G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE (glib/gobject)

Tags: c, gtk, glib, gobject

Some flutter code does this:

```
G_BEGIN_DECLS

G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE(FlTextureGL, fl_texture_gl, FL, TEXTURE_GL, FlTexture)

  gboolean (*populate)(FlTextureGL* texture,
                       uint32_t* target,
                       uint32_t* name,
                       uint32_t* width,
                       uint32_t* height,
                       GError** error);
};
```

I have to subclass the FlTextureGL class and define the `populate` function.

How to subclass a class defined with `G_DECLARE_DERIVABLE_TYPE`? How to define the method `populate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [tutorial](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/tutorial.html) on how to subclass with GObject, but the short answer is that you need to use the `G_DEFINE_TYPE` family of macros in your own code.

To define the `populate` method, you set the value of the function pointer in your `class_init` function:

```c
static void
my_type_class_init (MyTypeClass *klass)
{
  FlTextureGLClass *fl_texture_gl_class = FL_TEXTURE_GL_CLASS (klass);
  fl_texture_gl_class->populate = my_type_populate;

  /* ... */
}
```